How to access generic types when remapping keys
In TypeScript when I remap an object's keys from key to useKey and change the value into a function, how do I use some generic types that I give to another function so the end result has complete type-safety:
Playground Link (hover over the type of the hook and ignore JS errors)
const { useMyAwesomeResource } = handleResources({
  resources: {
    //                                TProps: TItem:
    myAwesomeResource: handleResource<string, AwesomeResource>({
      // do whatever
    })
  }
})

The result at the end should look like this (it uses TProps for first argument and TItem for result):
useMyAwesomeResource: (resourceId: string) => AwesomeResource

The code:
// func result:

type HookResult<TItem> = {
  data: TItem
}

type HookFunc<TItem, TProps> = (props: TProps) => HookResult<TItem>

type HookFuncs<TResourceHandlers> = {
  [Key in keyof TResourceHandlers as `use${Capitalize<
    string & Key
  >}`]: HookFunc<TResourceHandlers[Key]> // <--- how do I access generic types
}

// config you need to pass to the func:

type ResourceHandler<TRawItem, TItem> = {}

interface Config {
  resources: {
    [resourceName: string]: ResourceHandler<any, any>
  }
}

export const handleResources = (
  config: Config
): HookFuncs<typeof config.resources> => {
   // do whatever
})

// define the generic types:

const handleResource = <TItem, TProps = {}>(
  resourceConfig: ResourceConfig<TItem, TProps>
): ResourceInfo<TItem, TProps> => resourceConfig

I feel like I am missing one piece of this puzzle. I know it's possible as I use the library Redux RTK which has achieved this.

Found it. You can "infer" the types: type HookFuncs<TResourceHandlers> = {   [Key in keyof TResourceHandlers as use${Capitalize<string & Key>}]: TResourceHandlers[Key] extends ResourceConfig<infer TItem, infer TProps> ? (args: TItem) => TProps : never }

If you found it, please write up an answer so that future readers can see it (comments can be deleted at any time without history; answers can be undeleted but comments cannot)

TypeScript can "infer" types:
export type HookFuncs<TResourceHandlers> = {
  [Key in keyof TResourceHandlers as `use${Capitalize<
    string & Key
  >}`]: TResourceHandlers[Key] extends BaseResourceConfig<
    infer TItem,
    infer TProps
  >
    ? (opts: TProps & DefaultHookProps) => HookResult<TItem>
    : never
}

Now TypeScript can get your types automatically and knows about them all through this chain of types.
